# iPHone - Detect UITabBarController delegate methods?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want to be notified when the UITabbarViewController is loaded completely and is being displayed on the screen?

Since it's inheriting from UIViewController i tried setting the delegate to my appdelegate and implemented viewDidAppear, but it never get's called.

Any solution??

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
   self.tabbar.delegate = self;
   //other stuff
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"asdasd");
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set a delegate of UITabBarController you will only be able to override UITabBarControllerDelegate methods and not UITabBarController methods.

Solution: A

Create UITabBarController from code

Solution: B

Subclass UITabBarController

For both solutions you can either do you code within viewDidLoad or send a NSNotification with the info that the view is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a very elegant solution, but you could post a notification using [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:myNotification object:self];
```

and respond to it as follows:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dosomething:) name:myNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: how does this tell me when the tab bar is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Use the UITabBarController's `viewDidAppear`, inherited from UIViewController. The controller is responsible for the view's lifecycle, not the delegate.

Comment: Can you provide more details, it doesn't seem like the UITabBarController contains any UITabViewController.

Comment: Sure, the UITabBarController is a subclass of UIViewController. This means you have access to UIViewController's methods, including viewDidLoad:, viewDidAppear:, etc. Depending on how you are using the UITabBarController, you should be able to override the relevant method to accomplish your task.